# Angular Nested form fields using directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-include

I am trying to create a  form dynamically using server response. The form may have fields which are nested, grouped and so on. 
 I have tried creating a directive for my field type as 'form-field' and used ng-include directive to repeat for all the nested fields.

When i do this using a ul-li, the output looks correct but when i start using fieldsets and textfields the output does not render at all for the textfields.

```
    // Code goes here

angular.module('NestedForm', []).
controller('formController', function($scope) {


}).directive('formField',function($compile) {
  return {
        replace:true,
        require:'ngModel',
        scope:{
          data :'=data',
          ngModel : '='
        },
        restrict:'E',
        link : function($scope, $element, $attrs)
        {
          var type = $scope.data.type;
          var html = "";
          switch(type)
          {
            case 'textbox' :
              html = '<input id=\''+$scope.data.name+'\'  type="text" ng-model="ngModel" class="form-control">';break;
            case 'fieldset' :
              html = '<fieldset><legend>'+$scope.data.name+'</legend></fieldset>';break;
            default:
              break;
          }
          var $e =$compile(html)($scope);
          $element.replaceWith($e);
        }
  }
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/9b7wnPaaeppdJyq26qlN

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your question is too long. Many people just want to read question fast, understand, and answer if they know about it. If question is too long, we don't read fast, understanding is not correct, and answer does not come from the full understanding of your question.

I don'f fully read your question, but it seems you are replacing the full element.

Check this out.

http://plnkr.co/edit/01T5d4ngGviKI0jPafSO?p=preview

```
      var $e =$compile(html)($scope);
      $element.append($e);  //instead of replacing it
```

Comment: Sorry about the long post issue. For some reason, when i posted i had to place code and i placed the whole thing. Thanks for the solution. This solves my problem partially. I am trying to get the form-fields inside the <fieldset></fieldset>. Should i be using compile instead of link.

Comment: 1. because form cannot have a form, there is no nested form. You may say nested fieldsets.
2. fieldset is a container, and input field are items, it should have different directives.
3. within fieldset it generates html, including text and fieldset directives then compile it.